# Eager loading not pulling relationship model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

[Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) not pulling relation model.

Hi, Im using Laravel 6. Our database was created with Zend so our model is a bit strange; I have to set the primary keys.

```php
// Customer model

protected $table = 'customer';
protected $primaryKey = 'Customer_ID';

/**
 * Get all appointments for the customer.
 */
public function appointments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Appointment');
}
```

Then for the appointments

```php
protected $table = 'appointment';
protected $primaryKey = 'Appointment_ID';

/**
 * Get the customer assigned to this appointment.
 */
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
}
```

Now, in a controller:

```php
$appointments = App\Appointment::with('customer')->take(5)->get();
return response()->json($appointments, 200);
```

The array has the appointments but customer is null:

```php
{... Customer_ID: 1234, customer: null}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: which is the external key of the appointment table for the customer?

Comment: This might seem obvious, but you definitely have a customer record for the appointment you're querying right?

Comment: @GiacomoM that would be “Customer_ID”. It shows on the appointments results so the association is there.

Comment: @GBWDev yes, the is but it shows null. Im lost.

Comment: try to specify primary key, foreign key and table on the relations

Comment: Please post your migrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the relationship in the model, you can tell laravel which is the field of the foreign key.
If you do not do it, laravel supposes the foreign key is `id`, which is not your case.

The definition of the relationship should becomes:

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'Customer_ID');
}
```

Comment: I think I’ve seen this somewhere. Thanks. I’ll try in 15/30mins

Comment: Thank you very, very much!!